# how upload any file in alfresco without using enterprise edition?

Tags: upload, alfresco

I want to upload any file in alfresco.

[image: refer image task.png]

when I select any file and click on the `Complete` button then the selected file will be uploaded on alfresco server.

I am able to call tasklistner after click on the `Complete` button.

Could somebody write that function in java/javascript or suggest me any way to do this.

Comment: Are you using the new Angular components? CMIS? Something else?

Comment: it depends from the behaviour of the file component that you are using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot tell what your preferred language is, how you want to connect to Alfresco, what version of Alfresco you are running, what you've tried, or where you are stuck. But it is likely you need to take a look at the REST API. One way to do that is via the [Alfresco API Explorer](https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/).

Comment: thanx for reply,i did using rest api in java and javascript language :)